# FB Graph API is not returning user object in post's comments, likes, reactions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've FacebookApp [ type: business ] which fetches all posts, post-comments, and post-likes from the owned Facebook pages.

Verified permissions are `['pages_show_list', 'pages_read_user_content']`

When I'm fetching the post and their comments/likes then the user-object is missing in the response body.

**Sample JSON**

```
API : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/<PAGE-ID>/? \
fields=posts{message, comments{message, from{id, name, link}},reactions{from{id, name, link}}} \
&access_token={{pagetoken}}

response body sample : 

...
                "message": "For cancer awareness month we are sharing stories of survivors! \n\nManorama is sharing story ... Cancer Campaign (India)",
                "comments": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "message": "Thank u so much to the entire team.",
                            "id": "420757949533461_421416076134315",
                            // USER OBJECT IS MISSING : [id, name]
                        },
                        {
                            "message": "Thank u for sharing ma's story with all!",
                            "id": "420757949533461_421407146135208",
                            // USER OBJECT IS MISSING : [id, name]
                        }
                    ],
 ...
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the above API call because the API call is working fine with TestPage and TestUser. Do I need to ask for some additional permissions from Facebook?

Comment: How did you get the permission 'pages_read_user_content'? Is your app public?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Graph api does not return user's name anymore by calling this endpoint.

There is one solution you can try: use hooks.
Set a page webhook to retrieve all the comments written on your page. Find the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime

The comments' data you'll receive from facebook will contain a name